# Sort alphabetically a list with strings and lists of strings in Python

Tags: string, sorting, python-3.x, nested-lists

I have an assignment on logic and its relations, and at a certain step of an algorithm I have to be able to sort alphabetically a list with strings and lists of strings.

For example, something like

```
[['not', 'D'], ['not', 'C'], 'B', 'A']
```

should become

```
['A', 'B', ['not', 'C'], ['not', 'D']]
```

so that the unit strings (propositions) get sorted together with the strings on the second element of the lists (the not symbolizes the negation of a proposition and is constant).

So far, I was able to use `sorted(List, key=itemgetter(0,1))`, but this is only a trick for this very particular case and doesn't even work when the strings are literals, like the example above. Note that a string could be 'B' or 'Banana', the latter for which my quick fix works.

I appreciate your help, as I wasn't able to find a solution within all the questions placed here.

EDIT:

Another example is that

```
[['not', 'Pours'], ['not', 'Outside'], 'Rusty', 'Rains']
```

should become

```
['Rains', 'Rusty', ['not', 'Outside'], ['not', 'Pours']]
```

But I actually tried to go from the generic case I presented and create bigger words, and it indeed worked. So I guess the 'not' is having some influence here.

That is,

```
[['not', 'Dinossaur'], ['not', 'Carriage'], 'Banana', 'Apocalypse']
```

actually gets the correct form with the suggestion kindly provided by @inspectorG4dget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> L = [['not', 'D'], ['not', 'C'], 'B', 'A']
>>> L.sort(key=lambda x:(isinstance(x,str) and x) or x[1])
>>> L
['A', 'B', ['not', 'C'], ['not', 'D']]
```

Edit:

```
In [30]: L = [['not', 'D'], ['not', 'C'], 'B', 'A']

In [31]: L.sort(key=lambda x:(not isinstance(x,str), x if isinstance(x,str) else x[1]))

In [32]: L
Out[32]: ['A', 'B', ['not', 'C'], ['not', 'D']]

In [33]: L = [['not', 'Pours'], ['not', 'Outside'], 'Rusty', 'Rains']

In [34]: L.sort(key=lambda x:(not isinstance(x,str), x if isinstance(x,str) else x[1]))

In [35]: L
Out[35]: ['Rains', 'Rusty', ['not', 'Outside'], ['not', 'Pours']]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, it was very enlightening.
However, I tested it for the case the String had a dimension higher than 1 and the lists showed up before the unit strings. I believe another condition based on type is required, but without damaging the literal case. Do you have any suggestions to apply this efficiently?

Comment: @Alegom: Please edit your post to include an example of the problem you mentioned, as well as the expected/desired result

Comment: Post has been updated! I managed to do it in two steps, but I was hoping for a one step idea.

Comment: That is perfect, really appreciate your help on this!